# Placing items in sequence of array, with width = to percent of screen width

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I am testing a few things but have come across a problem or two.

I have this simple test JSON file:

```
{ "testData" : {
                "frequencies" : [
                {
                    "lowerNumber" :0,
                    "upperNumber" : 120,
                    "productCode" : 12001,
                    "useType" : "Aircraft"
                },
                {
                    "lowerNumber" :120,
                    "upperNumber" : 300,
                    "productCode" : 30001,
                    "useType" : "Tanks"
                },
                    {
                    "lowerNumber" :300,
                    "upperNumber" : 350,
                    "productCode" : 35001,
                    "useType" : "Mugs"
                },
                    {
                    "lowerNumber" :350,
                    "upperNumber" : 460,
                    "productCode" : 46001,
                    "useType" : "Fish"
                },
                    {
                    "lowerNumber" :460,
                    "upperNumber" : 550,
                    "productCode" : 55001,
                    "useType" : "Pies"
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to a: display some objects in order of the array they are parsed into and b: set the width of those items = to the upperNumber-lowerNumber percentage - so upper-lower / 1024pixels *100.

Here is my AJAX code which generates my array:

```
function loadParse(){

        $.ajax({
                  url : "src/testData.json",
                  dataType : "json",
                  success : function(parsed_json) {

                    objectsArray = parsed_json.testData.frequencies;

                    for (var i=0; i < objectsArray.length; i++) {

                        var newBand = new band(objectsArray[i].lowerNumber, objectsArray[i].upperNumber, objectsArray[i].productCode, objectsArray[i].useType, stage, i);
                    }
                  }
                });
    }
```

That's working fine, array makes sense, objects are displaying fine.  However they appear in the wrong order when I try to set the position on the X axis and the radius of the circles equivalent to the correct percentage value.  Here is my class:

```
function band(_lower, _upper, _productCode, _useType, _targetCanvas, _sequence) {
    _canvasWidth = _targetCanvas.canvas.offsetWidth;
    _canvasHeight = _targetCanvas.canvas.offsetHeight;

    function test() {
        var factor = ((_upper-_lower) / _canvasWidth)*100;
        var Circle = _targetCanvas.circle(50+((_sequence+1)*factor)*(10), 50, factor).attr({
            "fill" : "#f44"
        });
        var Text = _targetCanvas.text(50+((_sequence+1)*factor)*(10), 85, _useType);
    }

    test();

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing it failing?

Comment: I solved it, trying to figure out the best way to answer the question in case other people want to see the results. It's quite a large chunk of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this and am willing to share the code.  Basically I took the JSON file, placed those objects into an array, then sorted the objects by upper then lower number values.  I then iterated through that array and placed them on X according to a scaling factor.

A quick a dirty example can be seen here: http://andrewlarking.co.uk/lab/tateArtists/